# How can I animate an object in WebGL (modify specific vertices NOT full transforms)

Tags: javascript, animation, buffer, webgl, vertex

Okay,

I am new to 3D graphics and I want to animate individual specific vertices in a model **(NOT whole model transforms)**. My script is largely based off the NEHE webgl tutorial. In this tutorial all object vertices are stored in a buffer, which is initialized once when the program is first run. Here is the initialization code:
*Note vertices contains an array of vertices

```
vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
vertexBuffer.itemSize = 3;
vertexBuffer.numItems = parseInt(vertices.length/vertexBuffer.itemSize);
```

Now because these are initialized at the start, obviously changing the vertices array will do nothing. So I was wondering how is the best way to modify the vertices in real-time while still keeping it efficient enough to run smoothly.

Is it possible to rebind the buffer somehow eg run this code again at each animation tick?

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Cheers, J

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Okay after a whole lot of digging through the net. I have found the following changes must be made;
first of all, you must make the vertex array buffer dynamic. this is made possible by using the enumerator 'gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW' where previously in most tutorials we have 'gl.STATIC_DRAW'. Resulting in the following:

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

The second change must be triggered in your loop (or tick, or animation) function.
A new function is called in order to update the array. You must offcourse first bind the previous dynamic array buffer first:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
```

then after this you update the old vertices with the following function:

```
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, new Float32Array(vertices));
```

Where the parameters are <buffer_type>, <array_offset>, <new_data>

Source: http://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf

Hope this helps someone :)

J

Comment: This has helped me tremendously! I had the exact same question and you've provided a working solution along with a sensible explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason this answer and the original question have `bufferData` instead of `gl.bufferData`? I'm assuming typo but since it's carried through maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Good spotting, must have copied from the spec. Will update :)

Comment: You just made my project possible!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can follow the steps as explained in http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=239.

Here they keep the vertex data constant. Instead they keep changing the matrix mvMatrix which provides for the translations and rotations required. mvMatrix is then fed to the shader via a uniform variable and then multiplied by the vertex position to get the new vertex positions. Hope this helps.